# Ternary operation in TouchableOpacity

Tags: react-native

I try to use it like this but it gives me a "Do not nest ternary expressions" error.  How do I fix this?

```
<TouchableOpacity>
   {
     this.state.RefreshImage ? <Image source={require('../Images/add2.png')} style={{ height: 40, width: 40 }} /> :
    !this.state.RefreshImage && this.state.ButtonNumber === '1' ? <Image source={{ uri: imageUri }} style={{ height: 40, width: 40 }} />               
  }                      
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: The second ternary operation doesn't make any sense. Both options are exactly the same.

Comment: Oh sorry. Edited post @JJJ.  when I use like this it gives error. even I put ':' end of code , it gives still error

Comment: Now it makes even less sense. What should it show when the second condition is false?

Comment: @hakan There should be something to return for each ternary condition. Second ternary doesn't have anything to return in last part. Checkout my answer for same.

Comment: I tried ur answer before but it gives me same error  @Nirmalsinh

Comment: @JJJ  I have 3 button. When I press one of them it goes to Component 2 from Component1 and  when I come back to component1 from component2. I need to know which button I pressed in component1 so i can change  button's image. I want to do this

Comment: @hakan I tested the code and update my answer. Its working. You can take a look on updated code for this.

Answer (score 1):

The error (presumbaly from ESLint or some other linting tool) means that nested ternary operators make the code an unreadable mess. It's best to separate the logic outside JSX and use "normal" conditional statements so that the intention is clearer and it's easier to read. For example:

```
let image = null;

if(this.state.RefreshImage) {
  image = <Image source={require('../Images/add2.png')} style={{ height: 40, width: 40 }} />;
}
else if(this.state.ButtonNumber === '1') {
  image = <Image source={{ uri: imageUri }} style={{ height: 40, width: 40 }} />;
}

// ...

<TouchableOpacity>
    {image}
</TouchableOpacity>
```

(Note that `!this.state.RefreshImage && ..` is unnecessary in the second condition because that is already guaranteed by the previous condition to be true.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to return something into false condition of second ternary condidtion:

```
 return(
      <TouchableOpacity>
      {
        RefreshImage ? <Image source={require('../Images/add2.png')} style={{ height: 40, width: 40 }} /> :
       !RefreshImage && ButtonNumber === '1' ? <Image source={{ uri: imageUri }} style={{ height: 40, width: 40 }} /> : null
     }                      
   </TouchableOpacity>
```

My Tested code at local:

```
renderUpdate(){
    let RefreshImage = false
    let ButtonNumber = '0'


    return(
      <TouchableOpacity>
      {
        RefreshImage ? <Image source={IC_LOGO} style={{ height: 40, width: 40, backgroundColor:'blue' }} /> :
       !RefreshImage && ButtonNumber === '1' ? <Image source={IC_CHECKBOX} style={{ height: 40, width: 40, backgroundColor:'green' }} /> : <View style={{width:40, height: 50 , backgroundColor:'red'}}/>
     }                      
   </TouchableOpacity> 
    )
  }

  render() {

    return(
      <View style={{
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: APP_COLOR,
      }}>
             {this.renderUpdate()}

        </View>
    );
}
```

Without eslint rule:

```
  renderUpdate(){
    let RefreshImage = false
    let ButtonNumber = '0'
    let imageLocal = null
    if(RefreshImage){
      imageLocal = <Image source={IC_LOGO} style={{ height: 40, width: 40, backgroundColor:'blue' }} />
    }else if(!RefreshImage && ButtonNumber === '1'){
      imageLocal = <Image source={IC_CHECKBOX} style={{ height: 40, width: 40, backgroundColor:'green' }} />
    }else{
      imageLocal = <Image source={IC_BACKGROUND_IMAGE} style={{ height: 40, width: 40, backgroundColor:'green' }} />
    }

    return(
      <TouchableOpacity>
     {imageLocal}
    </TouchableOpacity> 

    )

  }
```

Comment: It still gives me error. at the first line, it says to me: Do not nest ternary expressions.eslint(no-nested-ternary)

Comment: Its due to rule of eslint. Checkout https://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/rules/no-nested-ternary for same. If you need to disable the rule or use other way, other than ternary.

Comment: You can simply use if else leader to get an answer.